# Can grub load a kernel from HTTP?

Tags: kernel, boot, grub, netboot

Typically the kernel file is loaded via disk.

#### Questions

- Is it possible to load it via HTTP/HTTPS?
- If so how?

Comment: `grub` can be compiled to support HTTP. [The friendly manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Device-syntax) says: _If you enabled the network support, the special drives ‘(tftp)’, ‘(http)’ and so on ars also available. Before using the network drive, you must initialize the network. See Network, for more information._

Comment: The manual? Who would have thought such a thing could contain useful information?

Comment: It would be interesting to know its syntax and if https is also supported. The mentioned manual by @yeti is a bit short on this subject. I came to this question after reading the manual and using google to find the answer.

Answer (score 4):

As @user62916 already mentioned, as long as you have the `http` module loaded, you can load a kernel via http like:

```
(http,host.lan)/path/to/vmlinuz
```

More info here on this excellent document: https://olbat.net/files/misc/netboot.pdf